# Dexguard vs Android plugin - breaks build process

Tags: android, ant, gradle, proguard, dexguard

When i try to use `dexguard` plugin in place of `android` plugin (`dexguard` plugin extends `android`), my `gradle build process` fails with this error:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/projectRoot/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectRoot:app'.
 Could not create plugin of type 'g'.
```

The first line build.gradle for my app module is

```
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
```

The build.gradle for my whole project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs 'path-to-dexguard/lib' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':dexguard:'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
```

I ran the `gradlew` with `debug` option enabled

```
$ ./gradlew --debug assembleDebug
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/builder/DefaultBuildType
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     at com.saikoa.dexguard.g.$getStaticMetaClass(DexGuard)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:2173)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:37)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     at com.saikoa.dexguard.g.<init>(DexGuard:90)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:65)
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     ... 46 more
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.builder.DefaultBuildType
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     ... 52 more
```

My `gradle` version is 2.1

```
$ gradle -v
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53
Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_07 (Oracle Corporation 23.3-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64
```

If i use android instead of dexguard, then i have no issues.

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: I have no issues running `ANT` independently - fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that you are using the DexGuard plugin with an incompatible version of the Android plugin. For each version of DexGuard, you can find the compatible version documented in the DexGuard manual > Gradle build. For reference, you can also find working samples in the directory `samples`.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to build it now Eric. But the apk file i got now refuses to install with error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED. How is Dexguard plugin different than Android that the resultant apk refuses to install? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: hey I am having the same error with dexguard on android studio: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] Any ideas?