# Gradle issue when upgrading from 0.14.0 to 1.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, dexguard

I've just upgraded my Android studio from 1.0 RC 2 to 1.0.1.

After that, I was prompted to update the gradle plugin from 0.14.0 to 1.0.0.

Once I did that, gradle build is failing with erro -

```
Error:No such property: GRADLE_SUPPORTED_VERSIONS for class: com.saikoa.dexguard.h
```

Has anyone else faced similar issues? Thanks a ton !

My build.gradle -

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    flatDir { dirs '../lib' } // For the DexGuard plugin.
    mavenCentral()               // For the Android plugin.

}
dependencies {
    classpath ':dexguard:'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'dexguard'
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro'),'dexguard-project.txt'
    }
    debug{
        //proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro'),'dexguard-project.txt'
        proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro'),'dexguard-project.txt'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you show your built.gradle?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418198/noclassdeffounderror-after-androidstudio-upgrade-to-1-0-december-8th/27418484#27418484

Comment: I tried that, Still the same

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149629/dexguard-vs-android-plugin-breaks-build-process

Comment: more one check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Android plugin 1.0.+, you should make sure that your are using DexGuard plugin 6.1.+.

You then need to apply both plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dexguard'
```

Finally, the Android plugin 1.0.0 requires Gradle 2.2.1.